# Scroll bar "jerks" while using position: absolute; in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need very fast parallax scrolling to make my background look like a spinning tire. When I use position: absolute; on the background image it works but the screen jerks back up at the end of scroll. When I take position: absolute; away the jerking stops but parallax scrolling is not working. I just want to be able to make the background image move very fast in relation to the foreground so any suggestions on how to fix this and or other methods of customizing parallax scrolling speeds?

I'm using bootstrap v4-alpha, and the cdn's for the jquery and popper from that version as well.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  $('body').css('top', -(scrollTop * 4) + 'px');
});
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("/pexels-photo.jpg");
  /*background-repeat: repeat;*/
  position: absolute;
}

form#search {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

form#search>div.d-inline-block {
  width: 29%;
  margin: .5%;
}

form#search>div.d-inline-block#quantity {
  width: 5%;
  margin: .5%;
}

form#search>div.d-inline-block>label,
form#search>div.d-inline-block>select {
  width: 100% !important;
}

h2.text-center {
  border-bottom: solid gray;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

div.main-content {
  margin-top: 5%;
  /*its right here*/
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}

footer>small {
  margin: 1%;
  ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-toggleable-md navbar-expand-lg navbar-inverse bg-inverse justify-content-between">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Cheapest Used Tires</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
<div class="navbar-nav">
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-dealers.php">Tire Dealers</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/why-used.php">Why Used?</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-knowledge.php">Tire Knowledge</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/tire-products.php">Tire Products</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>
</nav>


<div class="main-content container">
<h2 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Search For My Tires</h2>
<form id="search">
<div class="d-inline-block">
<label for="width-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Width</label>
<select id="width-search" name="width-search" class="d-block" required>
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="195">195</option>
<option value="200">200</option>
<option value="205">205</option>
<option value="210">210</option>
<option value="215">215</option>
<option value="225">225</option>
<option value="235">235</option>
<option value="245">245</option>
<option value="255">255</option>
<option value="265">265</option>
<option value="275">275</option>
<option value="290">290</option>
<option value="295">295</option>
<option value="305">305</option>
<option value="315">315</option>
<option value="325">325</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="d-inline-block">
<label for="aspect-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Aspect</label>
<select id="aspect-search" name="aspect-search" class="d-block" required>
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="60">60</option>
<option value="65">65</option>
<option value="70">70</option>
<option value="75">75</option>
<option value="80">80</option>
<option value="90">90</option>

</select>
</div>
<div class="d-inline-block">
<label for="rim-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Rim</label>
<select id="rim-search" name="rim-search" class="d-block" required>
<option value="">---</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="d-inline-block" id="quantity">
<label for="qty-search" class="d-block text-center font-weight-bold">Quantity</label>
<select id="qty-search" name="qty-search" class="d-block">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="text-center" style="width:25%">
<input type="submit" value="Search" style="width:25%; margin:1%;" /> 
</div>

</form>
</div>
</div>
<footer class="fixed-bottom text-white bg-inverse justify-content text-center ">
<small>O&O By TXJ</small><small>Powered by Funoto</small><small><a href="#" class="disabled ">Advertise with Us</a></small>
</footer>
```

**[Live Demo](http://demo.mobilifytech.com/)**

Comment: is there any link to inspect this page?

Comment: pointless snippet since it produces an `Error: {
  "message": "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"`

Comment: demo.mobilifytech.com

Comment: It automatically made the snippet, I'm not sure what that is about.

Comment: You have many `html` errors, unclosed tag and etc

Comment: Fixed the tags, the error is still there though.

Comment: These `html` errors not related to your problem but you must fix this then looking for problem, your problem belong to your `js`. but still i see some errors in `html` like `style="width=25%"`

Comment: In html  inside `<div class="text-center" style="width: 25%;">` but  you written`style="width = 25%;"`  correct this.

Comment: And please do not remove snippet, it added to see live demo and better debugging.

Comment: Okay, corrected that, sorry. I'm surprised my IDE didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove position absolute from body tag for smoother scroll.

Comment: remove the jquery of scroll top

Comment: create a blank div :
<div class="xyz"></div>
above the container div
add the following css
position fixed;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
bottom0;

you can get the effect.